# Entity : Error when adding an entry in a one-to-many relationship with self-reference

Tags: c#, api, rest, entity-framework

I'm trying to make an API to manipulate data from a MySQL database using Entity Code-First .

I have a Category class, which can have multiple subcategories, and only one parent. I already did similar classes, but this is my first time using a one-to-many relation and self-referencing, and I'm having trouble when adding a category.

Here is my code :

- Category.cs :

```
    public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column("parent_category_id")]
        public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
        [Column("name")]
        public String Name { get; set; }
        [Column("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ParentCategoryId")]
        public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Id")]
        public virtual ICollection<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }
    }
```

- ShopDbContext.cs :

```
    public class ShopDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }

        public ShopDbContext(DbContextOptions<ShopDbContext> options)
            : base(options) 
        {
            
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
                .HasOne(c => c.ParentCategory)
                .WithMany(c => c.SubCategories)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentCategoryId);
        }
    }
```

- CategoryRepository.cs :

```
    public class CategoryRepository : ICategoryRepository
    {
        private readonly ShopDbContext _dbContext;

        public CategoryRepository(ShopDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public async Task<Category> AddCategoryAsync(Category category)
        {
            _dbContext.Category.Add(category);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return category;
        }
    }
```

- CategoryController.cs :

```
    [Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository;

        public CategoryController(ICategoryRepository categoryRepository)
        {
            _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
        }

        // POST: api/v1/Category
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddCategory([FromBody] Category category)
        {
            await _categoryRepository.AddCategoryAsync(category);
            return CreatedAtAction("GetCategoryById", new { id = category.Id }, category);
        }
    }
```

My goal is to add the following category :

```
{
  "parentCategoryId": 0,
  "name": "First Category",
  "description": "The first category, without parent"
}
```

When I try my AddCategory function, I'm having the following error :

```
{
  "errors": {
    "SubCategories": [
      "The SubCategories field is required."
    ],
    "ParentCategory": [
      "The ParentCategory field is required."
    ]
  },
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "0HMPA9OFPSJK8:0000000F"
}
```

These field shouldn't be required, because the foreign key should fill these objects with  the corresponding datas in my database.

Did I mess up with my configuration ? My annotations ? I made many researches, and my "one-to-many" relationship seems good to me

Thanks for your help

Comment: You need `"parentCategoryId": null` for any root level objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After additional research, this is what I did to fix the issue :

- Category.cs :

```
    [Column("parent_category_id")]
    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }

    // [...]

    [ForeignKey("ParentCategoryId")]
    public virtual Category? ParentCategory { get; set; } = null;
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual ICollection<Category> SubCategories { get; set; } = new List<Category>();
```

- CategoryRepository.cs

```
public async Task<Category> AddCategoryAsync(Category category)
{
    if (category.ParentCategoryId == 0) 
        category.ParentCategoryId = null;
            
    // Add if I need parent in the response
    //if (category.ParentCategoryId != null)
    //{
    //    category.ParentCategory = await _dbContext.Category.FindAsync(category.ParentCategoryId);
    //}

    _dbContext.Category.Add(category);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return category;
}
```

For some reason, I need the "?" in `public virtual Category? ParentCategory { get; set; } = null;`, or I get the `The ParentCategory field is required` error. I will keep looking to simplify my solution, but at least I have a way to make it work.